# How to Dynamically Set Column Width in Oracle Apex

Tags: dynamic, format, oracle-apex, column-width

I have two classic reports that are dynamically created from a PL/SQL returning function. The data of each report generally contains the same data, but their column names are generally different.

I would like them aligned vertically, but the differences in column names makes the column widths different. My goal is to set each column width to the greater of the first or second report's column, for each column.  I think I'll just find the greater of each column length and multiple by a set pixel amount for that.

However, how would I go about setting the column width dynamically in the first place, for dynamically generated reports?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with some Javascript using the jQuery library built into APEX.

(WARNING: My Javascript isn't the world's most elegant!)

This worked for me:

1) In the "Function and Global Variable Declaration" attribute of the page create this function:

```
function setColWidths(colId) {
    var maxWidth = 0;
    $('th#'+colId).each (function (index) {
        w = $(this).width();
        maxWidth = Math.max(maxWidth,w);
        });
    $('th#'+colId).each (function (index) {
        $(this).width(maxWidth);
        });
}
```

2) In the "Execute when Page Loads" attribute of the page call the function for each column:

```
setColWidths('COL01');
setColWidths('COL02');
setColWidths('COL03');
```

You could perhaps enhance this solution so that you don't need to call the function explicitly for each column.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you @TonyAndrews. Quick question: my page actually has three reports on it, a main IR report, and the two Classic reports that I asked about in this question. The two classic reports are located on top, or come first, and the main IR report comes later. Why doesn't this code take the IR report into account? I wondered if your code would mess everything up because the column names in the IR report are much longer, but no it worked perfectly. I even added another $('th#'+colId).each ... into the function too see if that would have an effect, but it did not. -Matthew Moisen

Comment: The IR's column aliases are probably not COL01, COL02 etc.  I just created an IR with column aliases COL01, COL02 and it worked OK.

Comment: You are right, my IR is dynamically created from a collection and generates COL01.. columns, but I forgot that I have the report attributes dynamically generated as well and thus no TH#colId. Thanks again!